# Кирилица в регулярных выражениях на php

Tags: регулярные-выражения, unicode, кодировка, utf-8, php

Необходимо получить данные из файла, а затем изменить русские символы на английские предварительно поместив в нужный тег. Возникает проблема при выполнении функции `preg_replace_callback`. Она просто не находит русские символы. Но если создать строку с русскими символами, то тогда она сработает. Думаю, что дело в кодировке, при выполнении функции `mb_detect_encoding`, аргументом которой являются данные из файла, возвращается значение ASCII, в случае со строкой - UTF-8. Пытался преобразовать ASCII в UTF-8, ничего не вышло.

```
function cyrillicReplace(){
echo 1;
}

function mathRepl($matches) {
...
$matches[0] = preg_replace_callback('/[АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+/', "cyrillicReplace", $matches[0]);
// $matches[0] = preg_replace_callback('/[А-Яа-яЁё]+/i', cyrillicReplace, $matches[0]);
// $matches[0] = preg_replace_callback('/[\p{Cyrillic}]+/i', cyrillicReplace, $matches[0]);
...
}

$xml = file_get_contents($folder.$href);
$xml = preg_replace_callback('/<\w*?:?math[^>]*>(.*?)<\/.*?:?math>/i', "mathRepl", $xml);
```

Comment: Модификатор **u** ?

Comment: ничего не меняет..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251', 'rus_RUS.CP1251', 'Russian_Russia.1251');
```

Соответственно кодировку нужно свою поставить ;)